# $.each jQuery find common values between items

Tags: jquery, each

Given multiple items with class send-po each with data-loc=n

I have the following:

```
var qty = 0;
var loc = 0;
var product = '';
$('.send-po').each(function(i,item){
  qty = $(this).attr('data-qty');
  loc = $(this).attr('data-loc');
  product = $(this).attr('data-product');
});
```

What is the best way to group items when loc[0] = loc[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EynIx.png) or loc[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkbJY.png) etc?

I need to send a PO to a specific loc or vendor with all items shipping from a common loc(ation)

Thank you!

Based on mhodges suggestion I have done the following:

```
for(var o=0;o<100;o++){
  $('.send-po[data-loc='+o+']').each(function(i,item){
    console.log(item);
    qty = $(this).attr('data-qty');
    loc = $(this).attr('data-loc');
    product = $(this).attr('data-product');
  });
}
```

I think I can use this. Thanks mhodges!

Another, related issue:

```
var orders = '<table>';
$.each(cart,function(j,contents){
  if(contents[n].loc === contents[o].loc){
    //group the two 
  } else {
    orders += '<tr><td>'+contents.qty+'<br/>Sending from '+contents.loc+'</td><td>'+contents.product+'<br>'+contents.options+'<br>'+comments+'</td><td>'+number_format(order.Price,2,'.',',')+'</td><td>'+number_format(order.subtotal,2,'.',',')+'</td></tr>';
    orders += '<tr><td><input class="carrier" id="carrier_'+contents.cartId+'" placeholder="Carrier"></td><td><input class="tracking" id="cartid_'+contents.cartId+'" data-item="'+contents.product+' '+contents.options+'" placeholder="Tracking # for this item"><button class="btn-small send" id="send-tracking_'+contents.cartId+'">Send</button></td><td><input type="hidden" class="send-po" data-loc="'+contents.loc+'" data-product="'+contents.product+' '+contents.options+'" data-qty="'+contents.qty+'"><textarea id="afs-comments-'+contents.loc+'" placeholder="Comments to Vendor"></textarea><br/><button id="sendPO-'+contents.loc+'">Send PO</button></td></tr>';
    orders += '<tr><td colspan="4"><hr></td></tr>';
  }
});
orders += '</table>';
$('#orders').html(orders).show();
```

Right now I have 2 sets of output for each contents[] see graphic [image: what I have now])

What I need is to have the inputs and send PO only once per location: [image: only have the inputs once per location (contents.loc)]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use the data attribute in a selector to group items by a certain data attribute. Example: `$(".send-po[data-loc=0]")` will get you all of the items with the class "send-po" as well as a data-loc attribute equal to 0

Comment: interesting, I just don't know the value of data-loc - it can have 100 values possible

Comment: One thing you can do is grab a list of the data-loc values and then iterate over those. It may be too much to explain in a comment, so I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment:

> You can use the data attribute in a selector to group items by a certain data attribute. Example: `$(".send-po[data-loc=0]")` will get you all of the items with the class "send-po" as well as a data-loc attribute equal to 0

If you do not know which value you are looking for, or you wish to loop over all of the potential values, rather than guessing at how many you have and creating a for loop with a static set of values, you can actually retrieve the current list of values at any time and then iterate over those. That helps you in three ways:

1) It removes any unnecessary loop iterations / operations

2) It makes your code scalable and future-proof

3) It allows your data-loc values to be any value - strings, non-sequential numbers, etc.

Here's what the code might look like:

```
// Get the current list of all data-loc values
var locations = [];
$(".send-po[data-loc]").each(function () {
    var location = $(this).data("loc");
    // check to see if the value is already in the array
    if (locations.indexOf(location) === -1) {
        // if not, push it onto the array
        locations.push(location );
    }
});
locations.each(function (index, location) {
    // group the .send-po by data-loc value
    $('.send-po[data-loc='+ location + ']').each(function(i,item){
        console.log(item);
        qty = $(this).attr('data-qty');
        loc = $(this).attr('data-loc');
        product = $(this).attr('data-product');
    });
});
```

Comment: probably should not use location as it is a javascript keyword

Comment: @phpmydev location has never been a javascript keyword... https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/reserved-keywords

Comment: ok, come to think of it, it was length that I had a problem with not location, my bad!

Comment: @phpmydev What you are referring to are native properties on the `window` object, not keywords. Most of those properties are `read-only` and therefore the compiler will ignore any attempt set a variable with the "location" identifier on the GLOBAL SCOPE. In this case, however, a new variable (using var) is created and is scoped to the callback function on the `.each()`, therefore it will not have any correlation to the window.location property. If, however, you were to say just `location = "123"`,  it would ignore that and `console.log(location)` would give you the window.location object

Comment: @phpmydev What is interesting, however, is that if you place the var location ANYWHERE in the callback function, because of the "hoisting" effect of javascript, the window.location property will never be accessible as just "location" like it otherwise would be. For example, if you said: `function () { console.log(location); var location = "123"; console.log(location); }` you would actually get the local copy in both instances, the first instance would be undefined, the second instance would be "123"

Comment: @phpmydev And the same goes for length, console, and any other `read-only` property on the window object. The full list is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: thank you for the new education!  I misunderstand a lot of things, which is why I almost never actually post any solutions to peoples' problems.  I am quite a leech  in this regard, but I do my best to appreciate the help I do receive and you are no exception - I appreciate your help @mhodges